# Differences between AWS Ubuntu Image and a fresh install?

Tags: server, virtualbox, amazon-ec2

I've been using Ubuntu only on AWS for a year now. I'm now trying to set up a virtual environment as similar to my AWS one as possible, and I'm kinda confused.

When I spin up an AWS server, the magic box sets me up with the username Ubuntu and I log in with my key file and no password.. then I just get to business. In the Ubuntu setup, it encourages me to enter my full name and password. I have no issue with that, but I just want to be as similar to my AWS servers as possible.

What does an Amazon image have in it that a blank slate of Ubuntu server doesn't? What's the easiest way to emulate my existing installations on a fresh install? What are other differences I may run into?

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to run a virtual environment as similar to AWS as possible, then the easiest thing to do is to use the *exact* images that you'd boot on EC2.  Ubuntu "cloud images" are made available for download at http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/.

The "cloud images" are pretty much vanilla Ubuntu Server installs with the cloud-init package added.  In 12.04, they also have a 'ubuntu' user already added, but in 12.10 and beyond, cloud-init creates that user on first boot.

For information on how to use the images outside of a cloud, see [wiki doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images), or a [blog post](http://ubuntu-smoser.blogspot.com/2013/02/using-ubuntu-cloud-images-without-cloud.html) that I wrote.

Comment: Nowadays, Ubuntu Server comes with the `cloud-init` package installed too. So what's the difference now?